# SQL How to filter out an entire set of values dependent upon whether a single value of that set is equal to something?

Tags: sql, db2, mainframe

For example:

```
DEPT   ||   Y/N
-----     -----
GENRL     Y
GENRL     Y
GENRL     Y
GENRL     N

DNREV     Y
DNREV     Y
DNREV     Y
DNREV     Y

DNPAP     N
DNPAP     N
DNPAP     N
DNPAP     Y
```

I'm searching through ALL departments, but don't want to list any departments where at least one of the listings for it has a Y/N value of 'N'. In other words, I only want departments returned if every Y/N value for it is 'Y'.

The return I want from this would only be the DNREV department since all records for that department are 'Y'.

Answer (score 1):

Like with Venn diagrams you can remove the intersecting departments (those with 'Y' and 'N') using the MINUS operator.  In some database systems it's also known as EXCEPT. If you flip the order of the sub queries you get the opposite - all the dept's that had 'N' with no 'Y's.

```
select *
from t 
where dept in (
    select dept
    from t
    where y_n = 'Y'
    minus
    select dept
    from t
    where y_n = 'N'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

> In other words, I only want departments returned if every Y/N value for it is 'Y'.

You can use aggregation:

```
select dept
from t
group by dept
having min(y_n) = 'Y';
```

This uses the fact that `'Y' > 'N'`.

If you want full rows, use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.dept = t.dept and t2.y_n = 'N'
                 );
```

Comment: In this table I am selecting more than just those 2 columns I listed. Do I really have to list every column in the GROUP BY area? THere are 9 columns there.

Comment: @TroyN.Wingert . . . This answers the question that you asked.

Comment: It is still displaying departments that have at least 1 records with an 'N'. All the displayed values are the records with a 'Y', but I don't want a department to display at all in the output if it has a record on the table with an 'N'. This query you provided only sorts out the 'N' value records but leaves the 'Y' value records of departments that have an 'N' value on the table.

Comment: @TroyN.Wingert . . . That is not true of either query, unless you have a collage where `'N'` is greater than `'Y'` -- which is highly unusual.

Comment: So, one of the other columns is DEPT_ID. An example is DEPT_ID value of 28. This department, on the table, has some Y/N values of 'Y' and some of 'N', I do not want this department to show up in the results at all because some records have value 'N'. This query provided still returns that department, but only displays the records with a 'Y' value for that department rather than not returning it at all.